# Auto-updating serial number from a google sheets template

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am currently attempting to implement auto-updating serial number to a google sheet template.

The goal is: whenever the template is opened, the serial number goes up by 1 integer.

[Visual representation of what the process should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhqNK.jpg)

Is this possible using google sheets, if so, how would I go about making this a reality.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a script to do this.  I was able to replicate something similar with this code:

```
function onOpen() {
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A1');
  var value = cell.getValue();
  value = value + 1;
  cell.setValue(value);
}
```

Then you'd need to set up a trigger to run this function "From spreadsheet" "On open".